# basic javascript accordion

Tags: javascript, css

I am making an accordion FAQ. There are tons of scripts online, but I hate using scripts I don't understand (I'm new to Javascript). So I start from basic and work my way up. The following code is frustrating me as to why it doesn't work:

Javascript:

```
function faq1() {

var faq1 = document.getElementById("faq1")

if (faq1.style.display = "none") {
faq1.style.display = "block";
}

else {
faq1.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<a href="#" onclick="faq1()">Question 1</a>
<div id="faq1" style="display: none">
Answer to question 1
</div>
```

The script opens the accordion just find. However, the "else" portion of the Javascript doesn't work, when i click on the link a second time I can't get the display to turn back off. I have tried various methods of "else if's" to see if that would work with no luck.

Thanks guys

Comment: "I hate using scripts I don't understand (I'm new to Javascript)" - maybe this is the problem you should be addressing. While there's obviously value in reinventing the wheel for learning purposes, walk before you run. And IMO being able to use libraries based on the documentation should come before writing your own, ad-hoc, nonreusable replacements – that just sounds like setting yourself up for a maintenance nightmare down the road.

Comment: Also, have you tried using a debugger? Check whether `faq1()` even gets called, which lines get executed, and what the value of `faq1.style.display` actually is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`) in your condition.

Alternatively,

```
function faq1() {

    var faq1 = document.getElementById("faq1");

    faq1.style.display = faq1.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";

}
```

Comment: Well that was stupid of me. Thanks for the help, fixed it like a charm.

Comment: @user1935137 the polite thing to do would be to 'accept' their answer so they get the credit for the solution.